# Laravel Form-Model Binding multi select default values

Tags: php, html, laravel, binding, laravel-blade

I'm trying to bind a default value to a select tag. (in a "edit view").

I know this should be easy, but I think I'm missing something.

I have:

**User.php** (my user model)

```
...
    public function groups() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group');
}

public function getGroupListAttribute()
{
    return $this->groups->lists('id');
}
...
```

**UserController.php** (my controller)

```
...
public function edit(User $user)
{
    $groups = Group::lists('name', 'id');

    return view('users.admin.edit', compact('user', 'groups'));
}
...
```

**edit.blade.php** (the view)

```
...
{!! Form::model($user, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['UserController@update', $user->id]]) !!}
...

...
// the form should be binded by the attribute 'group_list' created
// at the second block of 'User.php'
// performing a $user->group_list gets me the correct values
{!! Form::select('group_list[]', $groups, null, [
                                'class' => 'form-control',
                                'id'    => 'grouplist',
                                'multiple' => true
                                ]) !!}
...
```

I did a dummy test in my blade, and have gotten the correct results:

```
@foreach ($user->group_list as $item)
     {{ $item }}
@endforeach
```

This lists the values that should be selected by default..

I also tried to put `$user->group_list` as third parameter from the `Form::select`, but this didnt work ether...

I have no clue what i'm doing wrong.. any hints on this one?

**edit**

when I do:

```
public function getGroupListAttribute()
{
    //return $this->groups->lists('id');
    return [1,5];
}
```

The item are correctly selected,

now i know i have to grab an array from the collection.. 
digging deeper.. :)

**found it**

**User.php:**

```
...
public function getGroupListAttribute()
{
    return $this->groups->lists('id')->toArray();
}
...
```

could it be easier?

Nice regards,

Kristof

Comment: jus fyi, you can do that without having to declare the `getGroupListAttribute()` method in `User.php`

Comment: I've faced a similar problem, instead of using *null* in the 3rd parameter of *Form::select* in your edit.blade view, put your $user attributes. Would be something like `$user->groups`. I have done this with single element dropdowns, but you have to test this out with multiple elements.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't put `null` in the `selected defaults` (3rd) argument.

```
{!! Form::model($user, ['route' => ['user.update', $user->id]]) !!}

{!! Form::select(
        'group_list[]',
        $groups,
        $user->group_list,
        ['multiple' => true]
    )
!!}
```

Comment: While this would work, if you do this you are no longer using model binding.